# Multiple iterations in the htmlextra report with newman

Tags: postman, newman

I am fairly new to using newman and I am trying to figure out how exactly to create multiple iterations within one report.
I cannot find the htmlextra.js file anywhere locally on my laptop (Win 10) to just change that field stated on: https://hub.docker.com/r/dannydainton/htmlextra

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5Fcj.png)

Can anyone please help me out on how to add more than 1 iteration to a collection for the reporter?

Thank you very much and sorry to bother you all with this basic question, but I just cannot figure it out.

Comment: Iteration is set through newman and not htmlextra report , for you can add newman run collection.json -n 5 -r htmlextra. For running collection 5 times . Are you looking something related to docker ?

Answer (score 1):

Iteration is set through newman and not htmlextra report , you can add iteration count through -n flag.

```
newman run collection.json -n 5 -r htmlextra
```

This will run collection 5 times

https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman will show all newman specific flag and

https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman-reporter-htmlextra shows all htmlextra specific flags

> -n , --iteration-count  Specifies the number of times the collection has to be run when used in conjunction with iteration
> data file.